# yii2 girdview pagination id list are showing but not showing link

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am New in yii2 going to add pagination it is showing list of id only botstrap  and link are not showing what is problem anyone explain me this is gridview

```
 GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'id' => 'grid',
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'user_fname',
            'user_id',
            'user_lname',
            'user_mobile',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        ],

    ]);
    ?>
    <?php
    echo yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'View' => 'usermaster',
        'layout' => "{pager}\n{items}\n{pager}",
    ]);
```

?>

This is search controller which is i have added pagignation class

```
  public function search($params)
    {
        $query = UsermasterModel::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,


             'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
                 ],
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'user_fname' => SORT_DESC,
                'user_fname' => SORT_ASC,
            ]
        ],

        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_fname', $this->user_fname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_lname', $this->user_lname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_mobile', $this->user_mobile]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have there both `GridView` and `ListView` on the same `$dataProvider`? Are you echoing GridView? There is no `echo` or `<?=` before it. Do you need pagination for GridView or ListView? It should work anyway.

Comment: but i am showing only list of id only how to show pagination like preview next

Comment: In ListView or GridView?

Comment: i need any one i am using list it is showing list of id

Comment: Have you got more than 10 items so pagination can be displayed? If there is less than set in `pageSize` pagination is not shown.

Comment: yes it is working fine

Comment: Add a screenshot to your question showing what you have got now.

Comment: the problem was in less than set so therefore it was not seen